# Blender has suddenly close

Tags: error

**System Information**
Windows 10 Home 64-bit (10.0, Build 17134) Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-7100 CPU @ 3.90GHz (4 CPUs), ~3.9GHz
Radeon(TM) RX 460 Graphics 8192MB RAM

**Blender Version**
Broken: Blender v. 2.79b has suddenly stop (close)
Worked: -

**Short description of error**
Blender had work normally before, but when my PC had been forced shutdown, it will occur that blender has suddenly close after i opened it
it happen in Blender Installer and blender Portable (.zip)
[image]
i had running in command prompt and it says
"Warning! Legacy WGL is unable to select between OpenGL versions.found bundled python: C:\Users\aflac\Downloads\blender-2.78c-windows64\blender-2.78c-windows64\2.78\python"

**Exact steps for others to reproduce the error**
Open file blender and it will suddenly close

**Have Tried**
I have tried to re-installing the driver, but it seems nothing change.
I uninstalling the driver with AMD Clean Up Utility and try to open the blender, it seems work properly although it has the warning 
"Warning! Legacy WGL is unable to select between OpenGL versions.found bundled python: C:\Users\aflac\Downloads\blender-2.78c-windows64\blender-2.78c-windows64\2.78\python"
and then I try to install the both version of AMD (Adrenalin Edition 18.5.1 & Adrenalin Edition 18.10.1 Optional) but it cannot open and it says again
"Warning! Legacy WGL is unable to select between OpenGL versions.found bundled python: C:\Users\aflac\Downloads\blender-2.78c-windows64\blender-2.78c-windows64\2.78\python"
It seems work properly before, but after updating the windows or something, it cannot work well.

P.S : I use command prompt to run blender with command --factory-startup to know the message on blender

i hope someone give me some advice for fixing it.

I hope you can fix it

Thank you

P.S : Sorry for bad english

---

**Update**
The message ""Warning! Legacy WGL is unable to select between OpenGL versions.found bundled python: C:\Users\aflac\Downloads\blender-2.78c-windows64\blender-2.78c-windows64\2.78\python" didn't appear, but blender didn't solve yet.
The Blender still suddenly close again after opened it, and i didn't fix it yet.

Comment: I can't comment but can answer this way, so:
maybe You should try to install older version of AMD graphic driver as something has changed in system and maybe it's not about blender itself.